# building table but get "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I try to build this table

```
 CREATE TABLE OFFICER 
(
ID int(8) PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
HIRE_DATE date NOT NULL,
UNHIRE_DATE date,
SALARY int(7),
PHONE_NUMBER int(10),
TYPE varchar2(15) NOT NULL
);
```

Do I have to use any constraint, reference? and What I lack for this code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

`INT` data type doesn't allow scale specification. Try either `ID int primary key` or `Id NUMBER(8) primary key`.

Comment: I try now, it's no effect

Comment: did you replace it for salary and phone number too?

Comment: Nope. But I've edited with your recommend, It can build now, thanks.

(I am new here)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
CREATE TABLE OFFICER 
(
ID NUMBER(8) PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
HIRE_DATE date NOT NULL,
UNHIRE_DATE date,
SALARY NUMBER(7),
PHONE_NUMBER NUMBER(10),
TYPE varchar2(15) NOT NULL
);
```